# Can you still drive a Stingray into the Iwajira boss fight?

Tags: borderlands-the-pre-sequel

I was wondering if that glitch was patched, but I am unable to verify it myself.

Is anyone able to verify that it is or isn't patched on the latest version?

Comment: I can check on PC this weekend if I get a chance.